# Pen pressure sensitivity in Paint Tool Sai doesn't work

Tags: 18.04, wine, playonlinux

I use Ubuntu 18.04, SAI 1.1.0 and Wine 2.12-staging. I've tried to install SAI with Wine 1.5.5-SAI before, but seem to have the same problem as user who asked this question: [Can You Run Paint Tool Sai on linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013903/can-you-run-paint-tool-sai-on-linux). Now SAI works, but can't sense pen pressure. Solution with TabletMouseSimulation=1 didn't work.